# Armadillo and C++ - Matrix initialization with 2D-array

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, armadillo

I need to initialize Armadillo matrix with the array of doubles. I've found this constructor in the original documentation:

```
mat(*aux_mem, n_rows, n_cols, copy_aux_mem = true, strict = true)
```

and I've found the question about it here on SO:

[armadillo C++: matrix initialization from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19370110/armadillo-c-matrix-initialization-from-array)

The problem is, it appears that the constructor works only for initialization with one-dimensional arrays, not 2D. If I try it to use this way:

```
double **matrix = new double *[block_size];
for(int i = 0; i < block_size; i++) {
    matrix[i] = new double[block_size];
}

arma::mat arma_matrix( &matrix[0][0], matrix_size, matrix_size, true, true );

cout << "am: " << arma_matrix[1][0] << endl;
```

I get the error:

```
fined_grain:103/init_function: In function ‘void place_user_fn_103(ca::Context&, ca::TokenList<double>&)’:
fined_grain:103/init_function:61:42: error: invalid types ‘double[int]’ for array subscript
```

So, what's the ideal way to initialize Arma matrix with 2D-array? I prefer the fastest solution, because I need to use big matrices.

Comment: @user3670482 - in my experience, the Boost matrix library is quite primitive compared to Armadillo

Comment: @user3670482 Unfortunately, I have to use Armadillo. Still, thank you for your advice ;-)

Comment: @mtall Have you tried exploiting Boost matrix with C++11 patterns? You might be able to do lots of cool things with that.

Comment: By the way, Martin, the guidelines for Modern C++ say that you should not use owning pointers, I.e. No new and delete. If you must use a pointer to deference the matrices, I'd say use a smart pointer like unique_ptr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a quick glance at the [armadillo library documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html) and I see the following problems.

1. The argument you are passing to `arma_matrix` is syntactically right but incorrect. You need to use:

   ```
   double *matrix = new double [block_size*block_size];
   arma::mat arma_matrix( matrix, block_size, block_size, true, true );
   ```
2. The syntax for accessing the elements is:

   ```
   cout << "am: " << arma_matrix(1, 0) << endl;
   ```

   You can also use:

   ```
   int row = 1;
   int col = 0;
   cout << "am: " << arma_matrix[row*block_size+col] << endl;
   ```

Comment: To avoid copying the memory, change `arma::mat arma_matrix( matrix, block_size, block_size, true, true )` to `arma::mat arma_matrix( matrix, block_size, block_size, false, true )`, ie. the 4th arg is changed to `false`.  This is faster, but see the caveats described in the [associated documentation notes](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#adv_constructors_mat) (eg. because you're now using the memory directly, you'll now be responsible for memory deallocation, handling aliasing, etc).