# Armadillo C++ - Initialize read-only matrix from const memory without copying

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, constants, armadillo

A very good answer to how to create an Armadillo matrix around existing memory is given here: [armadillo C++: matrix initialization from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19370110/armadillo-c-matrix-initialization-from-array/19372962#19372962).

I have a situation however where I would like to create an Armadillo matrix from a const array, without copying the data first. The first part is easy:

> - mat(const aux_mem*, n_rows, n_cols)
>
> Create a matrix by copying data from read-only auxiliary memory.

However this copies the memory first, which would be unnecessary in my case.

I would like to have something like this:

```
const double* ptr = start; // I cannot modify the source of this pointer

const amra::mat M(ptr, 4, 4, /*copy*/ false, /*strict*/ true);
```

However this exact constructor does not exist. Is there an alternative method that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [const_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast) to remove the `const` qualifier from the pointer.

In your case this is `const arma::mat M(const_cast<double*>(ptr), 4, 4, false, true);`

Comment: I had no idea it was possible to cast a const pointer back into a non-const pointer. I thought const pointer was a solid protection, but I guess it still remains up to the developer to respect it.

Comment: While this is the correct answer, usually it is considered bad practice to cast const away (https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#es50-dont-cast-away-const). You should at least make the arma::mat that you create this way also const to avoid allowing it to modify memory that should not be modified.